# Java encrypt logfile

Tags: java, encryption, logging

I am writing a web service that handles financial data which needs to be protected. Currently, I am developing and debugging the service but start to think of the production environment.

It is possible to log the sent payload --- the financial data --- for debugging purposes. This is the only way for me to see whats going on as a developer. The log information is written to a log file with java.util.logging.

Do you have an idea how I could encrypt the log file? Or do you have any suggestions how to make this secure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think rather than encrypting the entire file you could just encrypt the sensitive data, while keeping the other logging information intact. In this case you may need to create decrypting program as well.

Or better if possible when logging the data just mask it (like credit card numbers are masked using X character) so that it will be impossible to decrypt but the developer will be able to have an idea about what happened there. As per S.L. Barth's answer you could use built in encryption to do the encrypting.

Comment: +1 for the idea of simply masking the sensitive data. I suggest using a fixed-length mask, as the length of the masked data may also give information to snoopers. ("Is the amount in the 10s or the 1000s?")

Comment: +1 If you only need to log things to help in debug, masked log entries are enough. Otherwise, there is probably a DB with a transactions log.

Comment: Acutally, masking is a pretty good idea. I think I will stick with that. I can encrypt the payload in the database or something and just see if the communication works in the database... Great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java has built-in encryption facilities; the `javax.crypto` packages.

However, you probably don't want the logfiles themselves encrypted, you only want them to be encrypted when you send them over the net.
In which case, you should look for software for securely sending information; for example, a VPN.

EDIT: your problem is actually addressed in the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/BasicJava2/crypto.html).
From the looks of it, though, their example is vulnerable to a Man-In-The-Middle attack, as it does not seem to verify the origin of the sender like SSL/TLS does. So, I would recommend a VPN or other piece of third party software for secure transmission.

Comment: I think for financial data you'll want both. If the box is compromised you want the data to be encrypted as well as it can be.